# Prove $\mu(X) = 1$, and $E_1, \dots, E_n$ are measurable and $\mu(E_1) + \dots + \mu(E_n) > n - 1$, then $E_1 \cap \dots \cap E_n \neq \emptyset$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Using *integrals* prove that if $\mu(X) = 1$, and $E_1, \dots, E_n$ are measurable such that $\mu(E_1) + \dots + \mu(E_n) > n - 1$, then $E_1 \cap \dots \cap E_n \neq \emptyset$.

I did a similar proof but without integrals:

If $\mu(A) + \mu(B) > 1$ and $\mu(X) = 1$ then $A \cap B$ can not be empty, because if it were, we'd have $\mu(A) + \mu(B) > 1 = \mu(X)$, but since $A \cup B \subset X$ then $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B) - \mu(A \cup B) < 1 = \mu(X)$ which gives a contradiction.

I know that integral over a set $E \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\mu(E) = 0$ is 0, but that leads me nowhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $ \sum_{k=1}^n m(E_n) > n-1,$ then prove that $\bigcap_{k=1}^n E_k$ has positive measure.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398268/if-sum-k-1n-me-n-n-1-then-prove-that-bigcap-k-1n-e-k-has-posi)

Comment: Well, I want to prove it using integrals and the link you provided does not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the countably subadditivity of a measure (or induction) implies that
for $A_i$ measurable sets we have that
$$
\mu(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)\tag{0}
$$
See [Boole's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality). In particular
$$
\begin{align}
\mu(\cap_{i=1}^n A_i)&=\mu((\cup_{i=1}^n A_i^c)^c)\\
&=1-\mu(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i^c)\\
&\geq 1-\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(A_i^c)\tag{1}\\
&=1-n+\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(A_i)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
where in (1) we used (0).

In your case if  $\mu(E_1) + \dots + \mu(E_n) > n - 1$, then (2) implies that
$$
\mu(\cap_{i=1}^n E_i)>0
$$
and hence $\cap_{i=1}^n E_i\neq \varnothing$.